# Filter Collection with String Descriptor

Tags: c#, .net

Say I have `List` of objects that has some properties:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string s1 {get; set;}
    public string s2 {get; set;}
    public string s3 {get; set;}
}
```

I would like to filter this `List<Class1>` with a string, which let's say is in the format:

```
"s1=Hello,s3=Goodbye"
```

(perhaps via URL)

Of course I could parse the string the usual way, then cycle through through the filter items, compare to property names via reflection, etc.

But I was wondering if any one knew of a library or class that does something like this already? It's all rather tedious, and could be quite slow if not done properly, especially for a class with many properties. The problem sounds generic enough that I'm sure others have dealt with before, just wondering if anyone knows of any elegant solution?

Comment: Dynamic link can do this kind of thing http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks so much,Ben - this appears to be depend on the list being from a data provider that implements 'IQueryable'. But the list may have come from anywhere, e.g. the serialized result of a web service. `IEnumerable` should be the only restriction, really.

Comment: They are not properties without a get.  LINQ

Comment: @AFischbein You can convert any `IEnumerable` into an `IQueryable` by calling `AsQueryable()`

Comment: Thanks Ben - this worked great! If you don't mind posting it as an answer I would be happy to mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps (by using `Linq` and more specifically the `Where` clause):

```
var myList = new List<Class1> { new Class1 { s1 = "Hello", s3 = "Goodbye" }, new Class1 { s1 = "Goodbye", s3 = "Hello" } };

var filteredList = myList.Where(i => i.s1.Equals("Hello") && i.s3.Equals("Goodbye")).ToList();
```

`filteredList` will now contain only the first element from `myList`.

Comment: Thanks Sani. I should clarify that the solution should be able to handle arbitrary properties and values, not just the ones in my example. It should parse the string and apply the filters that are contained in it. Thanks!